# Watchface error upon loading

Tags: android, wear-os

SO , the whole project is located at github (https://github.com/Zarkopafilis/ZCycle)
I am facing this error while selecting the watch face from the android wear companion app , connected to an emulator (workspace: http://prntscr.com/5j21j5 , yes im using the latest android studio)... I dont know what to do , thanks in advance.

BTW this causes the emulator to pop a message saying 'Android Wear has stopped responding (ok button here)'

```
12-20 21:04:27.447      548-548/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.wearable.app, PID: 548
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.service.wallpaper meta-data
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1544)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
        at android.app.IWallpaperManager$Stub$Proxy.setWallpaperComponent(IWallpaperManager.java:249)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.home.stream.HomeView.setWallpaperComponent(HomeView.java:1546)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.home.stream.HomeView.setWatchFaceWallpaper(HomeView.java:1540)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.home.stream.HomeView.setWatchFace(HomeView.java:1426)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.home.stream.HomeView.dismissPickerAndSetCurrentWatchFace(HomeView.java:508)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.home.stream.HomeView$4.run(HomeView.java:487)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add missing meta-data (android.service.wallpaper) to AndroidManifest.xml.
Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html#RegisterService) guide for more information.

Comment: Which AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You may want to checkout the project again . I pushed the change in the missing meta data tag . Still error.

Comment: Your watch_face.xml is wrong. Replace PreferenceScreen by wallpaper and try again.

Comment: Meta-data does not start with wallpaper tag

Comment: So it's working now? I've tried and it works for me. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/b1B2ryS.png)

Comment: What setup are you using? @IzanRodrigo

Comment: Nothing special, I just clone your repo and deployed the APK.